# Maximal Munch: how do you know which tiles to make?

Tags: compiler-construction, tree, subtree

How do you know which tiles you have to make in a structured tree with Maximal Munch? What do they mean with 'the largest subtree possible'? Do they mean for each instruction?

Answer (score 0):

You define a tile for each machine instruction (e.g., "ADD Rn,+K" is represented by a tile "R+K"), for instructions that make sense for code generation  (some don't, e.g., "interrupt enable").   You also define a tile for each library routine that you expect might be useful for code generation (e.g., on a small computer, you likely don't have native multiply, so you'll define that as a library routine, e.g, "CALL MULTIPLY" represents "R1 * R2" ).

Then, given the set of tiles, the Maximal Munch method tiles the tree.